# Hide only pages on DataTable (not remove)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I am trying to get all the data on the dataTable and convert it to JSON, the problem is when the dataTable paginates it removes the DOM pages. What I want to do is to change the dataTables behavior on pagination, instead of removing the Pages on Pagination, it should just be hidden so I can still access the DOM.

Comment: For what reasons you want to access those elements on pagination. There are many features you can implement with `dataTables` even though the data is not present.. Please elaborate your problem properly..

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am doing a backend system and I want to give the user a preview before saving it on the server.

Comment: I want to save each of the datables columns all at once

Comment: Could you just get the table data from the server as json using ajax to get the full dataset rather than through the datatable?

Comment: That was what I was actually doing. My current update process is this: click a column-> show a pop-up->click update-> then update database.

Comment: @Dawcars you want me to make a temporary table storage?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to say for sure without knowing more about your code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly possible as DataTables doesn't support enabling and disabling features are run time. However, what you could do is make use of the **fnDrawCallback()** function to check to see if there is only one page, and if so hide the pagination controls.

```
                                 OR Try something like this
```

> `oTable=$j('#tablesorter').dataTable( {
>   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
>    "bFilter": false,
>    "bSearchable":false,
>    "bInfo":false,
>    "fnDrawCallback":function(){
>    if($j("#tablesorter").find("tr:not(.ui-widget-header)").length`

Comment: I have a huge data, it will always have to paginate

Comment: Dont want the webpage to be long